# Wordpress Import wp_posts into post table with different prefix

Tags: mysql, wordpress, foreign-keys

I would like to import all posts, including meta, tag, and category data into a new database with and existing posts table and different prefix.

So far I have tried using the Wordpress Import tool, however it created all new tables for me the old prefix. This is not what I want.

I've also tried exporting the table via phpMyAdmin. This method was unsuccessful as the many of the foreign keys are the same between the two tables.

Wondering if there is a script that will update the foreign keys on all of the table to keys higher than my oldest post row?

Answer (score 0):

you have change prefix using plugin or Custom.
if you use plugin "Change Table Prefix" 
or 
change here in wp_config file  $table_prefix  = 'xyz_'; 
and database table prefix change